# How does the unpublish/deletion of list items work in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007

I am currently working on a webproject, where we are using SharePoint 2007 WCM to create a new website for a large bank.

The questions I have are the following:

1. What happens when a user unpublishes an item from a list? 
   Especially when this item is used on multiple page throughout the site. Does SharePoint alert the user that the list item is used on several pages or does he delete them anyway, without warning.
2. What happens when a user unpublishes a reusable content item? 
   Especially when this item is used on multiple page throughout the site. Does SharePoint alert the user that the list item is used on several pages or does he delete them anyway, without warning.
3. What happens when a user unpublishes a image library item? 
   Especially when this item is used on multiple page throughout the site. Does SharePoint alert the user that the list item is used on several pages or does he delete them anyway, without warning.

Thanks in advance for the help,

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for 1 and 2:**
You can always set Content Approval [property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zreKQ.png) on Lists/Libraries, so that they may be approved before they are uploaded, deleted or changed!.

**Answer for 3:**
SharePoint will never allow you to delete an item of image library if this item is being used by other webpages. It normally says, "The file you attempted to delete is in use and is not allowed to delete".